# How to print Firestore timestamp as formatted date and time like December 28,2020 at 3:52:04 AM UTC+5:30?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs

while fetching date from firestore I am getting Timestamp  "seconds: 1608490949, nanoseconds: 275000000".I want to print it as properly formatted date and time. As it is "December 28,2020 at 3:52:04 AM UTC+5:30".
Below is my pic of code

```
    obj.modify=this.dateconversion(obj.modify);
    dateconversion( time:Timestamp){
      return time.toDate();
    }
    
    It is returning  me values "2020-12-27T22:22:04.000Z" but actual in firestore "December 28,2020 at 
    3:52:04 AM UTC+5:30".
    Its seems giving me 5 hours back that's why one day back data is printing.
    Can any one please suggest other way to do or where I am doing mistake.
```

Comment: Firestore timestamp type store dates in UTC and when you see on Google Console it gives you converted in local DateTime.
So tell me what does mean when you say it's returning.?
Which language you're using to communicate with firestore?

Comment: So, how I will convert as it is format like in earlier "December 28,2020 at 3:52:04 AM UTC+5:30" ??? while I am converting  date format (timestamp {second "123" nanoseond =12345) to date. I am using nestjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call javascript date functions here because this converting into javascript date

```
dateconversion( time:Timestamp){
  return time.toDate().toString();
  
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Or for more control on formatting, you can use momentjs [https://momentjs.com/docs/]